# Is it possible to bind an immutable set of certain type to an instance in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-8, singleton, guice

I am a complete beginner with Guice, and trying to achieve the following:

```
public class Apple {

    private final Integer size;
    public Apple(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}

public abstract class AppleModule {
   protected AppleModule() {

      ImmutableSet<Integer> sizes = ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3); 
      ImmutableSet<Apple> apples = sizes.stream().map(Apple::new).collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
      bind(new ImmutableSet<Apple>(){}).toInstance(apples);

   }
}
```

so that every time I declare something like `ImmutableSet<Apple> apppleBasket;`, I get the same list object injected. (but `ImmutableSet`s of other types still behave as normal)

But code above does not work with `bind(...)` saying `Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method error`

Note: I simplified the code I'm working on quite a bit while writing the question, so above might not compile out of box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a `Guice` module has to extend the `AbstractModule` class and override its `configure()` method. Second of all, if you want to bind generic types, you need to use [TypeLiteral](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html).

```
public class AppleModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    ImmutableSet<Integer> sizes = ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3);
    ImmutableSet<Apple> apples = sizes.stream().map(Apple::new)
      .collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());

    bind(new TypeLiteral<ImmutableSet<Apple>>(){}).toInstance(apples);
  }
}
```

Or, for example, you can use a `@Provides` method.

```
  @Provides
  ImmutableSet<Apple> provideAppleBasket() {
    ImmutableSet<Integer> sizes = ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3);
    ImmutableSet<Apple> apples = sizes.stream().map(Apple::new)
      .collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
    return apples;
  }
```

Please, use [Guice documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki) for additional information.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I didn't realize the TypeLiteral class, thank you!